# how to process large amount of images on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to process large amount of small images on HDFS. Hadoop provides archive API and sequencial file format to store large amount of small files in order to save memory on the name node. However, I need to retrieve the images which match my requirements after map-reduce. I am not sure but I think it might be difficult to retrieve images from both archive and sequencial file format. But if we don't use those methods we can choose to return the paths of the files and let server download those images from HDFS through those paths though it may give more pressure to namenode.I can't decide which scheme to use. Can anyone give any suggestions? I am really curious about how google stores their images on its data centers and return those images responding to users' query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at HBase which will allow you to store small files and random read/write on the one hand and fully participate in map/reduce jobs on the other